# Socket em C - Teste de conexão entre cliente e servidor (Linux)

Tags: c, socket

Estou trabalhando com sockets em comunicação de sistema embarcado. Eu crio uma thread para tratar a conexão, porém como o meu sistema utiliza conexão Wi-Fi eu preciso realizar de alguma maneira um teste de conexão antes de enviar ou receber, para caso essa conexão caia eu trata-la logo de reconectar. Alguém teria alguma ideia, de como realizar esse teste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei uma biblioteca chamada [libping](http://www.joedog.org/libping/index.php) encontrei ela no [vivaolinux](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/ICMP_ECHO-(ping)-em-C-C++)

Abaixo um exemplo de uso (também encontrado no link acima)

---

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ping.h>

int
main( int argc, char *argv[1] )
{
    if( pinghost( argv[1] ) > 0 )
        printf( "%s is alive\n", argv[1] );
    else
        printf( "%s is unreachable\n", argv[1] );

    exit( 0 );

}
```

---

Espero ter ajudado